# Asp.net MVC 5 Ajax call modal dialog

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I am new to asp.net MVC 5, I wonder how to use Ajax to call the modal with partial view? i had tried some code but the modal doesn't show up. Any body help?
Here is my code:

View

```
    <script>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

                // Create
                $(".modalCreate").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Create","Category")',
                success: function () {
                        $(this).attr('data-target', '#createCat');
                        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
                    // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
                    $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                        $('#createCat').modal('hide');
                    });
                    //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
                    $('#createCat').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                    });
                    $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
                        return false;
                    });

                    // Init JQuery Validation for view
                    $("form").removeData("validator");
                    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    displayAjaxError(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>


<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Create Category ", "Create", "Category",
        null, new { @class = "modalCreate btn btn-success" })
</p>

<div id="createCat" class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_Create");
    }

    // POST: /Category/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoryCreateVM productcategory)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProductCategory cat = Mapper.Map<CategoryCreateVM, ProductCategory>(productcategory);

            db.ProductCategories.Add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Message"] = "New Category added sucessfully.";
            ViewBag.Message = "New Category added sucessfully.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView(productcategory);
    }
```

and partial view:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
            {
}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I using the boostrap default theme to do. I try to debug in browser inspection it doesnt show any error. But I can sure is it able to find my partial view but the modal never show up. I hope that anyone can help me check my code.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well this is the way:
1- add your Modal Template in `"<script>"` part of `Views->Shared->_Layout` whith specific id for each part of modal to use it every where you want, for example:

```
<!-- Modal start-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modalid" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabelid">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBodyid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal End-->
```

2- then add code below in any view that you want use modal :

```
<script>
function functionname() {
        $("#Modalid").modal();
        $("#ModalLabelid").html("YourTitle");
        $("#ModalBodyid").load("url of partial view or anything that you want show in modal body");
    }
</script>
```

now if you want load body of modal from some partialview , write the url in .load() method :

```
$("#ModalBodyid").load("/Controller/Action/");
```

and if your action should get parameter, add the name of parameter exactly as in action entire :

```
$("#ModalBodyid").load("/Controller/Action/" + NameOfParameterinAction);
```

finally to use your script you should call `functionname()` every where you need from any View :)